# ANGULARJS How to keep controllers tidy when managing view logic?

Tags: angularjs

After reading these articles I've been trying to decouple my app:

http://toddmotto.com/opinionated-angular-js-styleguide-for-teams/

http://toddmotto.com/rethinking-angular-js-controllers/

One of the insight of the articles is this one:

> Controller drives Model changes, and View changes. Keyword; drives,
>   not creates/persists, it triggers them!

I've found easy to manage persistent data in my services but I still need to create data in the controllers to handle view state changes or transforming data from the services.

Is there a pattern to avoid creating ANY data in the controller while being able to manage the view?

Comment: You still need to use the Controller to bind data model values to $scope.

Comment: You may want to look at his updated https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide and https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide as well.

Comment: Also it can be a ViewModel(generally used without noticing) not a Controller. Look at MVVM(Model-View-ViewModel).